# Small text filtering within span elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking for filtering text (descriptions) from Google results. It is included in a  element.
I have done as follows:

```
result_div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'})
```

where  `result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})`

but it returns a null value.

How would I be able to get this?

Code I tried:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
s = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
s.send_keys("stackoverflow")
s.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
result_div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'})
```

Comment: Please share the _full_ code you have tried with providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Well, `result_div` is a list of type `bs4.element.ResultSet`. So, when running your code I get `ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'.`. Have you done the same? or are you looping over `result_div`?

Comment: I was looping over `result_div` : `for r in result_div: r.find('span', attrs={'class': 'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'})`, but then I removed it since I thought it was wrong

Comment: Are you only trying to get the description text? or also other information?

Comment: only description text. The problem is in capturing the right reference/tag element. I am not understanding which class/element I should get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple classes named `g`, not all of them contain a nested class `VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc`.
Since all you want is the description, just search for the class `VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc` directly:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
s = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
s.send_keys("stackoverflow")
s.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")


for tag in soup.find_all("div", class_="VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers.
Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in ...
The Stack Overflow Podcast is a weekly conversation about working in software development, learning to code, and the art and culture of computer programming.
The Stack Overflow podcast is a frank and funny conversation about what it means to work in software and how code is reshaping our world. As it celebrates its ...
Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million ...
5 days ago — For the past five years, the Go user survey has consistently identified Stack Overflow as the #1 place users go to find answers to their Go ...
```

Comment: Thank you MendelG. One question: what was it wrong in this line of code: `r.find('span', attrs={'class': 'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'})`? Would it have worked differently? Just to understand if it could have been fixed it

Comment: @Math Because this class `VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc` is not directly under the class `g`, there are several other tags in between.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you so much